# Poincaré inverse square law unification

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law, interactions

A while back, I came across a claim that was something like this: Poincaré said that no two fundamental force laws could have the same mathematical form such as $1/R^2$; that no two fundamental force laws can share the same fundamental constants. So, that somehow everything is fundamentally electromagnetic in nature.

Is anyone familiar with this idea?
And is there any source where this idea is explained--in English?
I tried reading this, but it’s not on point:
https://www.science20.com/relativity_and_beyond_it/henri_poincare_predicted_the_existence_of_gravitational_waves_as_early_as_june_5_1905-165539

And looked at this, but I don’t read French well: Oeuvres de Henri Poincaré t.9.
https://archive.org/details/uvresdehenripoin09poin

And this, but it’s too advanced for me: On the dynamics of the electron:
http://henripoincarepapers.univ-nantes.fr/chp/text/hp2007gg.html

Comment: *Somehow everything is fundamentally electromagnetic in nature.* If Poincaré said that, he was wrong, according to today’s mainstream physics.

Comment: Link to claim? Which page?

Comment: From here: On the Dynamics of the Electron  (1905) by Henri Poincaré, translated from French by Wikisource
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Dynamics_of_the_Electron_(July) 
Poincaré : So if the inertia of matter is exclusively of electromagnetic origin, as it is generally admitted since the experiment of KAUFMANN, and except that constant pressure from which I come to speak, **all forces are of electromagnetic origin**, the postulate of relativity can be established in any rigour. It is what I show by a very simple calculation founded on the principle of least action.